# Using wildcard in string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, wildcard

How can one represent a range of numbers in a string in javascript?

So for example,

var Ages = "This member is x years old";

where x can be any nunber at all.

I want to be able to search for such string in an array of strings.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), that should be able to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a regular expression, match and capture `\d+` (one or more digits) in place of the `x`:

```js
const pattern = /This member is (\d+) years old/;
const input = prompt('Input?', 'This member is 99 years old');
const match = pattern.exec(input);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
} else {
  console.log('Format not recognized');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is really good for concatenations.

`var x = // the age value you are searching for;`

`var ages = "The member is " + x + " years old";`

You can then just wrap this in a loop.

Comment: This is probably not the most efficient way to do what you are trying to do as others have said here, its best to use regular expressions.

Comment: Yea, using regular expression is the right approach